# Android: TypedArray.recycle() - what does it do, why is it important?

Tags: java, android

So I'm looking at

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/TypedArray.html#recycle()

Which is used in some code I've been going over, and the docs line is a little vague:

```
public void recycle ()

Added in API level 1
Give back a previously retrieved array, for later re-use.
```

Normally I would assume this to be a garbage collection assistant, but the method call doesn't - as far as I can tell from the docs - clean up my reference to the array.  Is it that different threads are in action and you get concurrent modification exceptions if you don't 'give back' control of the TypedArray?

What does "give back" mean in this context?

Comment: I think they keep a pool of those objects. Recycle makes it again available to other views

Comment: I did find:

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21097861

But i'm not sure if that applies here or not...  I assume it must, but it would be nice if the docs clarified that a bit.

Comment: I can not answer to your second question. About the first one.. well Somebody could argue that having the source code available is enough.. still the documentation is not perfect (and it will never be, imo). Still if the ask to recycle it...

Comment: Yea I did some more reading and it sounds like you're correct in regards to the pooling in this case.  And I'm not making an argument against following the docs recommendation, I'm more curious why/what the recommendation is for.

Comment: @blackbelt if you want to post some links or somethign to how you have this knowledge i would accept your answer.